# Hominidae is to hominid as Poaceae is to what?

Tags: botany, taxonomy, nomenclature

I considered asking this on English.SE, but decided against it, since it strictly applies to biological nomenclature, which not many of them will know about - particularly that of plants.

So, in animals, all families end in the suffix  -idae - e.g. Hominidae, Apidae, Canidae or Laridae. When referring to members of a family, you can use the suffix -ids - e.g. hominids, apids, canids or larids.

However, plant families are usually named with the ending "aceae" - such as Poaceae, the grass family. If I want to refer to members of Poaceae (without just saying the common name), what do I say?

Comment: Is this a question for an assignment or are you asking out of more general interest?

Comment: @BryanKrause Out of general interest, for the most part. Plus, it may come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Since *Poaceae* is the plural of *Poacea* in Latin - like *aquae* is the plural of *aqua* - I would say *a Poacea*, but I'm not a native English speaker so I don't know if this form would be acceptable in English. My guess is that you will have to use the long form *a member of Poaceae*. In languages like Italian and French it's easier because the Latin nomenclature and grammar are translated. So in Italian you will say *una Liliacea* for the singular and *due Liliacee* for the plural, while in French it would be *une Liliacée* and *deux Liliacées* respectively.

Comment: Seems like most people just call them grasses (or they use the actual family name). I wouldn't suggest using Poacea.

Comment: +1 for "a member of Poaceae." Don't use "a Poacea". Definitely don't try the *-id* ending since that is used for several larger plant clades (e.g. "Rosid" is a much larger category of plants that includes Rosaceae).